# Calculate the rotation and position of a cuboid after a force is applied from the corner

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics

For context I am trying to make a basic simulation of a rover landing on a planet. If I have a cuboid and I apply an upwards force from one of the bottom corners how would I calculate the rotation and position of the cuboid after the force has been applied? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

realistically if that force is applied and we can assume that the cuboid will rotate around of one of its bottom edges. In that case you can calculate the moment of inertia I and by resolving

\begin{equation}
I \alpha = Fr
\end{equation}

where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration ($s^{-2}$) and r the distance between the rotation axis(in this case one of the edges) and the point where the force is applied you can calculate the position of the cuboid (angle of inclination from the surface). This is a simplified solutions and if you need more details we can discuss in the comments.